# How do I capture the Text of a TextBox during a KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox

I'm trying to write a page that filters a `ListBox` depending on the contents of the `textbox`. I've got all the other stuff working but I want the ListBox to apply the filter with every `KeyDown` event that occurs in the TextBox. The problem is, when I capture the KeyDown event and then try to look at the TextBox.Text property, it remains empty. I imagine that this is due to the fact that the TextBox may only update the Text property when it loses focus.

Any thoughts on how I can get the current text in a `TextBox` during the `KeyDown` event without having to capture and rebuild the character array during each `KeyDown`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx):

> For keyboard input, WPF first sends the appropriate KeyDown/KeyUp events. If those events are not handled and the key is textual (rather than a control key such as directional arrows or function keys), then a TextInput event is raised.

In the KeyDown event, you can capture the key that's pressed:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Key);
}
```

After the event exits, the pressed key is added to the `.Text` property, so the next time the KeyDown event is raised, you can read the previously entered characters from `.Text`.

Comment: Also handle TextChanged so you can notice copy-pastes

Comment: This isn't the behavior I'm seeing. It seems that the TextBox.Text isn't being applied until the TextBox loses focus.

Comment: @jermny when inside the first KeyDown event that occurs, the `Text` property will still be empty.

Comment: Ahhh.. the TextBox.TextChanged was what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
private void OnKeyUpHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null){

       MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
     }
}
```